# Simple way to reading/writing NSAttributedString in iOS?

Tags: ios, rtf

In Mac OS X, there is AppKit addition which supports reading and writing of NSAttributedString as RTF format.

Equivalent in iOS? Should I make my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you just want to save the string to the disk? I would use NSCoding for that.

To write an object to a file:

```
result = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:attributedString toFile:archivePath];
```

To read an object from a file:

```
attributedString = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:archivePath];
```

You can do this with any object conforming to "NSCoding", and it's fairly easy to add support for NSCoding to your own classes. More information can be found at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1