# Swift save the text of UITextView in file with attributes

Tags: ios, swift, file, text, uitextview

I want to save in a file the text of UITextView with attributes (as Font, Color..).

I used the method:

```
pathtext = "...\nameFile.txt"
textView.text.writeToFile(pathtext, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

But it save only the text without attributes.

Which extension of the file should I use?
If this isn't possibile, how can I save the text in other way?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Do you want to save formatted text (fonts, colors etc) in a .txt file? Text files only support raw text, without styles.

Comment: No, i know that the extension 'txt' is wrong. But i don't know how i can save the text.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5317789/543224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
textView.attributedText
```

to retreive the text content with its formatting attributes.